# Why is $\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^2 x, x\rangle$?

Tags: operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $A\in \mathcal{B}(X)$ be self-adjoint. 
How can I prove: $$\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^2 x, x \rangle$$

I know it is a simple problem, but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not true in general. Is $A$ a Symmetric operator?

Comment: I think you need $B$ to be self-adjoint, in which case it follows from $BB^*=I$ and the inner product identity for the adjoint.

Comment: yes, $A$ is self-adjoint. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $A$ is [symmetric](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Symmetric_operator) or [self-adjoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator), just use the $\color{red}{\text{definition}}$: $\langle A^2x, x\rangle = \langle A(Ax),x\rangle\color{red}{=}\langle Ax, Ax\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. it's a very very simple question. thanks :)